# How to effectively visualize a recursive function?

Tags: r, recursion

I'm currently in the process of teaching recursion in a programming class. I noticed how hard it is for my students to grasp the concept of recursion. Is there a nice way to visualize what the function does for the pedagogical purposes?

As an example, here is an R function for getting the n'th Fibonacci number:

```
fib_r <- function(n) {
    if(n <= 2) return(1)
    fib_r(n-1) + fib_r(n-2)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: First I want them to understand how the function works. A bonus would be to explain the efficiency.

Comment: How so? Could you give an example?

Comment: Thanks @RHertel I fixed it. (p.s.: I teach it in Hebrew, so there I don't use the English spelling)

Comment: Perhaps this will help them understand: http://stackoverflow.com/a/234868/3521006

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would go about explaining recursive functions in `R`:

First, I agree with @AEBilgrau that the factorial is a good example for recursion. (Better than Fibonacci in my opionion.)

Then I would quickly go through the theoretical basis why the factorial can be defined as a recursive function, something simple like

> 4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 4 * 3!

Then you could present them the respective recursive `R` function

```
fact = function(x) if (x == 0) return(1) else return(x * fact(x - 1))
fact(3)
#6
```

**but** present them also the following output

```
#|fact(3) called
#|fact(3) is calculated via 3*fact(2)
#|fact(2) is unknown yet. Therefore calling fact(2) now
#|Waiting for result from fact(2)
#|  fact(2) called
#|  fact(2) is calculated via 2*fact(1)
#|  fact(1) is unknown yet. Therefore calling fact(1) now
#|  Waiting for result from fact(1)
#|  |   fact(1) called
#|  |   fact(1) is calculated via 1*fact(0)
#|  |   fact(0) is unknown yet. Therefore calling fact(0) now
#|  |   Waiting for result from fact(0)
#|  |   |   fact(0) called
#|  |   |   fact(0)=1 per definition. Nothing to calculate.
#|  |   |   fact(0) returning 1 to waiting fact(1)
#|  |   fact(1) received 1 from fact(0)
#|  |   fact(1) can now calculate 1*fact(0)=1*1=1
#|  |   fact(1) returning 1 to waiting fact(2)
#|  fact(2) received 1 from fact(1)
#|  fact(2) can now calculate 2*fact(1)=2*1=2
#|fact(3) received 2 from fact(2)
#|fact(3) can now calculate 3*fact(2)=3*2=6
#[1] 6
```

as derived from

```
# helper function for formatting
tabs = function(n) paste0("|", rep("\t", n), collapse="")

fact = function(x) {
  # determine length of call stack
  sfl = length(sys.frames()) - 1
  # we need to define tmp and tmp1 here because they are used in on.exit
  tmp = NULL
  tmp1 = NULL
  
  # on.exit will print the returned function value when we exit the function ...
  # ... i.e., when one function call is removed from the stack
  on.exit({
    if (sfl > 1) {
      cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(", x, ") returning ",
          tmp, " to waiting fact(", x + 1, ")\n", sep="")
    }
  })
  cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(", x, ") called\n", sep="")
  if (x == 0) {
    cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(0)=1 per definition. Nothing to calculate.\n", sep="")
    # set tmp for printing in on.exit
    tmp = 1
    return(1)
  } else {
    # print some info for students
    cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(", x,
        ") is calculated via ", x, "*fact(", x - 1, ")\n", sep="")
    cat(tabs(sfl),"fact(",x - 1,
        ") is unknown yet. Therefore calling fact(",
        x - 1, ") now\n", sep="")
    cat(tabs(sfl), "Waiting for result from fact(",
        x - 1, ")\n", sep="")
    #call fact again
    tmp1 = fact(x - 1)
    #more info for students
    cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(", x, ") received ", tmp1,
        " from fact(", x - 1, ")\n", sep="")
    tmp = x * tmp1
    cat(tabs(sfl), "fact(", x, ") can now calculate ",
        x, "*fact(", x - 1, ")=", x, "*", tmp1,
        "=", tmp, "\n", sep="")
    return(tmp)
  }
}

fact(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my example, probably used in quite a few textbooks:

```
recursive_sum <- function(n){
  if(n == 1) {print("Remember 1, add everything together"); return(n)}
  print(paste0("Remember ", n, ", pass ", n-1, " to recursive function"))
  n + recursive_sum(n-1)
}
```

Output:

```
> recursive_sum(4)
[1] "Remember 4, pass 3 to recursive function"
[1] "Remember 3, pass 2 to recursive function"
[1] "Remember 2, pass 1 to recursive function"
[1] "Remember 1, add everything together"
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the factorial function is a good example for recursion. Combining this with a printout (as others suggest) seem like a good way to describe what is going on:

```
factorial <- function(n) {
  cat("factorial(", n, ") was called.\n", sep = "")
  if (n == 0) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(n * factorial(n - 1))
  }
}

factorial(4)
#factorial(4) was called.
#factorial(3) was called.
#factorial(2) was called.
#factorial(1) was called.
#factorial(0) was called.
#[1] 24
```

You can also then implement a non-recursive factorial function and compare the computational efficiencies. Or maybe ask them what is problematic with the above implementation (e.g what happens with `factorial(-4)`).

Regarding a more proper visualization (and not just easy examples), there are [websites](https://visualgo.net/recursion) which illustrate the recursion tree.

**Edit:** [Googling recursion](https://www.google.dk/search?hl=en&q=recursion&gws_rd=cr&ei=Mb8-WKT0N7Lb6QTu-6vYCQ) is also a useful lesson.

Comment: I like this, but it might not be sufficient. What the students also need to see is how the results are then passed upwards all the way to the first call of `factorial`. I would actually use a blackboard here.

Comment: @Roland I would use the blackboard too. Alternative a website like the one i link to now where the recusion tree (of both fibonacci and factorial) can easily illustrated could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of the variable **n** in the **fib_r**

```
print("iteraction at: ", n)
```

Comment: I used in class "print" inside the recursive function, but I felt this was not enough.